# $[(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2, \hat{a}] = -2\hat{a}^{\dagger}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I'm confused by a line in the following wikipedia article on [the squeeze operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_operator) in deriving the action of the squeeze operator on Heisenberg basis, the article seems to imply that
$$[(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2, \hat{a}] = -2\hat{a}^{\dagger}.$$

I'm confused by this, because as I expand $$[(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2, \hat{a}] = (\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2\hat{a} - \hat{a}(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2 = \hat{a}^{\dagger}[\hat{a}^{\dagger}, \hat{a}]\hat{a}^{\dagger}=-(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^{2}.$$

I'm wondering if there is typo in the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $\left[\hat{a}, \hat{a}^{\dagger}\right] = \hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger} -\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} = 1$,
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
[(\hat{a}^{\dagger})^2, \hat{a}] &=& \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} - \hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}^{\dagger} \\
&=& \hat{a}^{\dagger} \left(\hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger} - 1\right) - \left(\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} + 1\right) \hat{a}^{\dagger} \\
&=& \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger} - \hat{a}^{\dagger} - \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger} - \hat{a}^{\dagger} \\
&=& -2\hat{a}^{\dagger}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: ...don't give it away so easily...

Comment: Meh, I appreciate the clear response. I know it's important to struggle generally.

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in your equation, namely $$\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}\hat{a} - \hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger 2} \neq \hat{a}^\dagger [\hat{a}^\dagger, \hat{a}]\hat{a}^\dagger \,.$$

The correct equation is
$$\hat{a}^{\dagger 2}\hat{a} - \hat{a} \hat{a}^{\dagger 2} = \hat{a}^\dagger [\hat{a}^\dagger, \hat{a}] +[\hat{a}^\dagger, \hat{a}] \hat{a}^\dagger \,.$$